# Nativescript : error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: interface, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

tns 2.3.0

I've defined a User interface :

```
export interface User {
  name: string,
  pictureUrl: string,
  coverUrl: string
}
```

chat.service :

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getChat() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + Config.token);

    return this.http.get(Config.apiUrl + "/chat", {
      headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(res => {
      console.log("Chat:")
      console.log(res)
      console.log(res.participants.me.name)
      let chat_data = res;

      let me : User = {
        name: chat_data.participants.me.name, 
        pictureUrl: chat_data.participants.me.pictureUrl,
        coverUrl: chat_data.participants.me.coverUrl
      };

      let other : User = {
        name: chat_data.participants.other.name, 
        pictureUrl: chat_data.participants.other.pictureUrl,
        coverUrl: chat_data.participants.other.coverUrl
      };

      let messages : Message[] = chat_data.messages;

      let chat : Chat = {
        participants : {
          me : me,
          other: other
        },
        messages : messages
      }

      return chat;
    })
    .catch(this.handleErrors);

    handleErrors(error: Response) {                    //line 58
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
      return Observable.throw(error);
    }

  }
}
```

When building, I get the following error trace :

> app/shared/chat/chat.service.ts(58,23): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> app/shared/chat/chat.service.ts(58,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Answer (score 1):

In your instantiation, you have a comma at the end of the second line and a semi-colon at the end of the third and fourth lines:

```
let me = new User {
    name: me.name,                   <-- comma
    pictureUrl: other.pictureUrl;    <-- semicolon
    coverUrl: other.coverUrl;        <-- semicolon
  };
```

Even knowing as little about Nativescript as I do, I'm guessing this is not right (based on the error messages and my knowledge of general syntax rules).

> If that's true, by the way, you're probably better off deleting the question since it will almost certainly be closed as a simple typo.

Comment: Correct I think it's just JavaScript syntax in general. Don't quote me on that though :)

Comment: @paxdiablo Im sorry there was a mistake, ive updated the post.

Comment: @moaglee Yeah, this error is typo as interface is object properties defined and every property is separate by comma as it isn't end of command change semicolon to comma and will work

Comment: @MarekMaszay Please check the post again, this is the actual code and it does not have a ;

Comment: @moaglee interface has same rule it must have commas not semicolon so probably its that thing that causing error

Comment: @MarekMaszay I removed the ; I still get the same error. Plus, wonder why it occurs at line # 58